# Haskell data type within data type

Tags: haskell, types

Say I have a data type like `data Shape = Circle Size | Rectangle Corner` and `Size` and `Corner` are also different data types like `data Size = Big | Small deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)` and `data Corner = Blunt | Sharp Size deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)`

I want to write a function that would return `Big` instead of `Circle Big` . What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: How about `f x = Big`? That fits the requirement.

Comment: Start by giving a type decl for this function. (That's always a good answer "to approach" something in Haskell.)

Comment: What should the function return if it’s not `Circle Big`? What if it’s `Rectangle Blunt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather you want a function that extracts the shape's main attribute, so something like:

```
> getAttr (Circle Big)
Big
> getAttr (Rectangle Blunt)
Blunt
> getAttr (Rectangle (Sharp Small))
Sharp Small
```

Technically, this is possible.  You can write a type class:

```
class GetAttr a where
  getAttr :: Shape -> a
instance GetAttr Size where
  getAttr (Circle s) = s
instance GetAttr Corner where
  getAttr (Rectangle c) = c
```

to define such a function, but you do have to help GHCi out with the types:

```
λ> getAttr (Circle Big) :: Size
Big
λ> getAttr (Rectangle Blunt) :: Corner
Blunt
λ> getAttr (Rectangle (Sharp Small)) :: Corner
Sharp Small
```

If you ask for the wrong type, you'll get a runtime error:

```
λ> getAttr (Rectangle Blunt) :: Size
*** Exception: OneAttribute.hs:9:3-24: Non-exhaustive patterns in function getAttr
```

so it might be return a `Maybe` instead:

```
class GetAttr a where
  getAttr :: Shape -> Maybe a
instance GetAttr Size where
  getAttr (Circle s) = Just s
  getAttr _ = Nothing
instance GetAttr Corner where
  getAttr (Rectangle c) = Just c
  getAttr _ = Nothing
```

giving:

```
λ> getAttr (Rectangle Blunt) :: Maybe Corner
Just Blunt
λ> getAttr (Rectangle Blunt) :: Maybe Size
Nothing
```

Now that you have this function, though, you'll generally find it isn't very useful.  Pretty much every time you use it, you'll discover that you already know exactly which attribute type, `Size` or `Corner`, to expect, and so you can replace `getAttr` with the much simpler and clearer functions:

```
getSize :: Shape -> Maybe Size
getSize (Circle s) = Just s
getSize _ = Nothing

getCorner :: Shape -> Maybe Corner
getCorner (Rectangle c) = Just c
getCorner _ = Nothing
```

or dispense with the functions entirely, and case-match directly on your `Shape` when you find yourself needing to extract the shape's main attribute:

```
printAttribute :: Shape -> String
printAttribute (Circle s) = "shape: " ++ show s
printAttribute (Rectangle c) = "corner: " ++ show c
```